# Why absolute positioning doesn't work when moving menu elements down in Bootstrap Navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Navbar with two menu elements aligned to the right:

[image: Current location at top of Navbar]

The point is that **I would like those elements to be aligned to the inferior border of the bar** and I would prefer using absolute positioning rather than playing with their padding and margins. As you can see in the Firebug screenshot below those menu items are childs of a div that covers the precise area where I would like to position them (for those not familiar with firebug the blueish area corresponds to the browser position of the underlined code):

[image: HTML code with parent underlined]

[image: Browser position of parent]
​
Now, my question is, why adding the css `.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right{ position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; width: 230px; }` results in the menu elements moving further to the right of the area of its parent? **I would expect them only to move down, not right.** (Result shown below with firebug still shadowing its parent position).

[image: Location after using absolute position]

**Disclaimer:** As you can check below (another firebug screenshot) `.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right` corresponds indeed to the child of the previously underlined div:

[image: HTML code underlining .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right]

[image: Browser correspondence of .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right]​
​
**Bonus:** Any help moving down these menu elements without using padding and margins and keeping them within their parent's area will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An absolute positioned element is generally not influenced by any other element. To get it working, give the parent element a `position: relative;`.

```
.navbar-collapse {
    position: relative;
}
```

Then the absolute positioned element is dependent on its parent element.